# gcc 2.95 floating point linear algebra not matching gcc 4.3.2

Tags: linear-algebra, floating-point-precision

I am compiling legacy code that calculates color spectra using linear algebra.  The matrices use float as the type, and all calculations use float.  When we use our old compiler (turbo-linux gcc 2.95) we get one answer.  When I use our new compiler (SuSE gcc 4.3.2) we get different spectra.

I need to get the output of the same program compiled using the new compiler to match the output using the old compiler.

I have tried using these compiler options:
 g++  -g  -lstdc++  -mfpmath=no-sse -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -ffloat-store -mieee-fp

and this code:

```
volatile unsigned short int cw;
__asm__ volatile("fstcw %0" : "=m" (*&cw));
printf("floating point control word was: %x\n",cw);
cw=0x027f;
__asm__ volatile("fldcw %0" :: "m" (*&cw));
    printf("floating point control word  now is: %x\n",cw);
```

None of this enabled the color spectra to match.

The question is then... is there a silver bullet to make the color spectra resulting from code compiled from the two different compilers to match?  I was hoping the floating point control width (the flpcw above) was the solution, but it wasn't.  (note, the code is too complex to post, ).

P.S. the result of the above code was:
gcc 2.95 floating point control word was: 0x37f
         floating point control word  now is 0x27f.

gcc 4.3.2 floating point control word was: 0x37f
          floating point control word  now is 0x27f.

Comment: Show an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. And why `-mno-sse2`?